# Not able to send push notifications in cloud code

Tags: ios, parse-platform, geolocation

I have saved all the user's location in the installation object. And i have another object named locationObject which gets updated when the current user sends his current location.When it does, i want to compare his current location with all the other saved locations and send push notifications to the users who are nearby.This is my code but this does not seem to work.

```
//this code should run when the locationObject is updated
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("locationObject", function (request) {
    var geoPoint = request.object.get("myCurrentLocation");
    var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    pushQuery.near("significantLocationUpdate", geoPoint);
    pushQuery.limit(100);
    pushQuery.find({
        success: function(results) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                //console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
                for (i = 0; i < results.length; 1++) {
                    Parse.Push.send({
                        where: pushQuery,
                        data: {
                            alert: "some user is nearby" 
                        }
                    }, {
                        success: function() {
                            console.log("push was successfull")
                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            console.log("sending push failed")// Handle error
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                console.log("failure");
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I can see a few issues - you have `1++` instead of `i++` in your loop, you are both executing the query and including it in your push and you don't use the results from your query/loop - either simply include the `pushQuery` in your push or use the results to generate individual push messages.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i restructured the code.And it works. Thanks to Paulw11

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("locationObject", function (request) {
    var geoPoint = request.object.get("myCurrentLocation");
    var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    pushQuery.near("significantLocationUpdate", geoPoint);
    pushQuery.limit(100);

    Parse.Push.send({
        where: pushQuery,
        data: {
            alert: "some user is nearby"
        }
    }, {
        success: function() {
            console.log("push was successful");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("sending push failed")// Handle error
        }
    });
});
```